# How do I change the value of a field using odoo migration manager?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I created a migration folder with a pre-migration file in odoo to change the value of a field in odoo, but the migration seems not be triggered.

I created a pre migration file like this2

```
import logging
from odoo import SUPERUSER_ID, api
from openupgradelib import openupgrade

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@openupgrade.migrate()
def migrate(cr, version):
    env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})

    logger.info("-----Renaming Project Templates-----")

    if planning_project := env["project.project"].search(
        [("name", "=", "Planning")], limit=1
    ):
        planning_project.write({"name": "Location Qualification"})

    logger.info("----completed------")
```

my file structure for the migration is

```
migrations
    15.0.1.0.0
        pre-migration.py
```

But this seems to have no effect when i update the module

Answer (score 0):

Change the `version` entry of the  `__manifest__.py` file of your module... to match your folder name:  15.0.1.0.0 :

```py
"version":"15.0.1.0.0"
```

This match (or version above) will trigger your script in pre-migration.py
To manage it (without understanding why), i had to:

- in a 1st commit: increment the version of the migration folder above the module's version
- in a 2nd commit: increment the module's version to get equal to the version of the migration folder